# how to keep dynamically changed html after a res.(anything)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express

I have a registration form with some input fields like username, email, ...
I also have a script that validates the from when the submit button gets clicked (the labels of the input field turns red when the field is empty) but the submit button also sends a post request to the server. On the server there is alse some validation and when there are no validation errors on the server-side a user is made and saved to the DB. But I don't know what i should do when there are validation erros.

-If I just use return to jump out of the function, the page keeps loading (because it waits on a response i think)

-And if I use a res.redirect(to the same page) or res.render(the same page) the  labels of the input field are not red anymore but i want to keep them red so the user sees what he has done wrong.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Comment: All requests need to return a response (otherwise the browser just waits a really long time for a response to come).  If you're submitting the form via Javascript, then you just need to return a response from your server that indicates a validation error when the form doesn't validate and your Javascript that gets the response needs to see and understand the error and put the right info on the screen for the user to see.  One simple scheme is to return a JSON response with a "status" property that your Javascript can check and act accordingly.

Comment: return a json response with an error message and display the error on the form.

Comment: As the guys above said... but also, if you're already aware that the page has validation errors (because you've already highlighted red), why are you sending the request?

Answer (score 1):

A: Please share your code?
B: why aren't you validating the form on front-end and not calling the API in case there are errors?
C: Ok, If there is validation on the back-end you don't have to just jump out of the function just send an error response which you can handle on the front in the `.then()` of the ajax call.

P.S share your code!